# How can I hide filters while downloading a Tableau worksheet as PDF or Powerpoint?

Tags: tableau-api

I want to download a Tableau dashboard as a ppt, but I want the filter controls to be hidden, is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to do this is to build the visualisation and then include it in a dashboard.

Tableau dashboards are designed to allow you to control the way things are visualised. They can include multiple visualisations. More importantly for your purpose, they allow you to control what the layout shows and where it shows it. So including a single visualisation in a dashboard gives you the option to remove filters and other elements you don't want users to see or pdfs/powerpoints to print.

It may be that you have are building dashboards. If so, the trick is to realise that anything can be omitted from the visualisation.